# Perl DBI 2 dynamic arrays in 1 query

Tags: perl, dbi

I currently have a webpage with 2 multiselect boxes that returns 2 different strings, which will be used in my SQL queries.

I am currently only using 1 string in my queries, but wish to add another and am unsure of where to go from here.

I have the string being created into an array

```
@sitetemp = split ',', $siteselect;
my $params = join ', ' => ('?') x @sitetemp;
```

and am able to use a query with `$params`

```
$mysql_inquire = "SELECT starttime, SUM(duration) FROM DB WHERE feature = \"$key\"  and starttime >= $start and starttime <= $end  and site IN ($params) group by starttime order by starttime";


 $sth = $DBH->prepare($mysql_inquire);
 $sth->execute(@sitetemp);
```

Essentially my question is how could I do the same thing, using 2 different arrays?

I assume the line `$sth->execute(@sitetemp, @otherarray);` would not work.

Comment: Did you try? It would work.

Comment: As long as the number of `?` in the string is the same as the number of values you pass to `execute()` you will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your approach will work.**

You can pass as many arrays into a function as you want. Arrays are just lists of values.

Consider the following example:

```
sub foo {
    print Dumper \@_;
}
my @a = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my @b = ( 4, 5, 6 );
foo( @a, @b, ( 7, (8), 9, ( ( (10) ) ) ) );
```

This will print:

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          7,
          8,
          9,
          10
        ];
```

When you say `foo(@a, @b)` it will just evaluate each array into a list. And you can combine as many lists as you want, they will always be *flattened*.